# How to remove part of data while doing a bufferzon? Arcmap GIS

Tags: buffer, gis, spatial, arcmap

I have an assignment where I have to make a buffertzon 5km around every grocery store. I later make a spatial join between the buffertzone and the population of the people to see how many live within these areas.
The next step of the assignment is to remove one of the grocery stores to see how many people would be affected if one closed down.
I don't understand how to remove just one grocery store from the data or if there are different ways to solve my problem.
I'm very new to this so please let me know if I didn't explain well enough. I'll upload photos that will hopefully clarify some more.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want the grocery store called Rottnahallen to be removed. It is located in the buffertzon in the village called Uddheden.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ61h.png

Answer (score 0):

Those green dots are population? If they are, you can make a select by location using the population and the specifically grocery store buffer, so the number of green dots selected would be the number of people affected.

You can make a clip too, using the green dots as Input Features and the grocery store buffer as Clip Features.